# creating dynamic for loop in VBA excel

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I have tried to create dynamic for loop with the start and end numbers being variables. However, the code cannot get into the for loop with the changed start and end numbers. How could I solve my problem?

Here is my code

```
Sub row_column()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("origin_boundary")

Row = 1

Dim Start As Integer
Start = 2
Dim Last As Integer
Last = 41

For x = Start To (Last + 1)

If ws.Cells(x, 1) <= Row * 40 Then
ws.Cells(x, 6) = Row

Else
If ws.Cells(x, 1) > (Row * 40) Then

Row = Row + 1
ws.Cells(x, 6) = Row
Start = (Row - 1) * 40 + 2
Last = Start + 39

End If

End If

Next x






End Sub
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Code as is will go through a For loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For x = Start To (Last + 1)` loops `x` from `Start` value to `(Last + 1)` value.

- The first time loop runs, `x = 2` because `Start = 2`.
- The second time loop runs, `x = 3` because 3 comes after 2. `Start`
  doesn't have a role here so there is no point changing the
  value of `Start`. Instead, you can change the value of `x` like `x = 
  (Row - 1) * 40 + 2`.
- `Last = Start + 39` can be dynamic if you want, but it won't matter until
  `x` reaches the value of (dynamically changed) `Last` value. You can use `x` instead of `Start` here.